# How to list data from firebase in React V9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Good Morning I need to retrieve Data from firebase realtime DB to my react project .
How can I write the code in .js file to retrieve structure like the below assuming that I have Barcode as input.

```
 {
  "Product1": {
    "Barcode": "11",
    "Name": "Cream",
    "Price": "30LE"
  },
  "Product2": {
    "Barcode": 22,
    "Name": "Vitamine",
    "Price": "40LE"
  }
}
```

I don't know what to write to retrieve the price of  certain barcode ? the barcode will be the searching criteria and it will change based on the input from react project
what I should write  retrieve the price of  certain barcode  ?

Comment: Have you checked [sorting and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) section in the documentation? Also can you please share any code that you've tried so far?

Comment: React is up to v18. How have you missed 10 updates? And you haven't added any React code to your question as a [mcve] so this is not possible to debug.

Comment: OP seems to be referring to [Firebase V9](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade)